# Divs arrangement error on Chrome

Tags: html, css

Im having headaches by trying to fix a small error that appears only in CHROME.
On [the index of my website](http://www.lumeatapetului.ro/uk/) i have 3 containers with little images,and they appear nice on IE and FF,but on CHROME there's a displacement of the second container which i dont know how to fix. 
 This second container is a bit more problematique because it has some mouseover effects with big baloons as tooltips,and if i manage to put all 3 containers in the same line,the tooltips will be displayed only partially.

Please take a look and,if you can,give me few hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine too me. I'm using a beta build of chrome, so I think it's just a bug in chrome and is fixed in the next version

Comment: You've asked 8 questions and you've accepted 0 answers?

Comment: I'll review all my posts today and see what answers resolved my problem and i'll rate the authors. Just slipped,sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is rather schizophrenic. You are attempting to use `position:relative;` in conjunction with `display:inline` and `float:` to position these elements.

Pick one method and use it consistently.

I would recommend floating them, or using `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: @ pbfy0 : thank you,but i must make it work on older versions also.  @ Chris Sobolewski : thanks a lot,mate! i didnt know the relationships between the display,float and position attributes.   Lots of thanks again.